# Recursively deleting all files and folders from a given FTP path

Tags: c#, ftp

I am trying to create a program that will recursively delete all files and folder from a given FTP path. My program is working well, if there are only a few files or directories in a given path. For some reason though, if there are several files in a directory, it just hangs on the `ReadLine()` line and eventually gets an IO error. Here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    private const string FtpSite = "myftpsite.com";
    private const string FtpUserName = "myusername";
    private const string FtpPassword = "mypassword";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DeleteFilesAndFolders("/");
    }

    private static void DeleteFilesAndFolders(string path)
    {
        if (path != null && (path.StartsWith(@"\\") || path.StartsWith("//")))
            path = path.Remove(0, 1);
        List<FileObject> files = DirectoryListing(path);

        foreach (FileObject file in files.Where(file => !file.IsDirectory))
        {
            DeleteFile(path, file.FileName);
        }

        foreach (FileObject file in files.Where(file => file.IsDirectory))
        {
            DeleteFilesAndFolders(path + "/" + file.FileName);
            DeleteFolder(path + "/" + file.FileName);
        }
    }

    private static void DeleteFile(string path, string file)
    {
        var clsRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + FtpSite + path + "/" + file);
        clsRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FtpUserName, FtpPassword);

        clsRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;

        using (var response = (FtpWebResponse) clsRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream datastream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (datastream == null)
                    return;
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(datastream))
                {
                    sr.ReadToEnd();
                    sr.Close();
                }
                datastream.Close();
                response.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void DeleteFolder(string path)
    {
        var clsRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + FtpSite + path);
        clsRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FtpUserName, FtpPassword);

        clsRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.RemoveDirectory;

        using (var response = (FtpWebResponse)clsRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream datastream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (datastream == null)
                    return;
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(datastream))
                {
                    sr.ReadToEnd();
                    sr.Close();
                }
                datastream.Close();
                response.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    private static List<FileObject> DirectoryListing(string path)
    {
        var regex = new Regex(@"^([d-])([rwxt-]{3}){3}\s+\d{1,}\s+.*?(\d{1,})\s+(\w+\s+\d{1,2}\s+(?:\d{4})?)(\d{1,2}:\d{2})?\s+(.+?)\s?$",
            RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
        var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + FtpSite + path);
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FtpUserName, FtpPassword);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;

        var result = new List<FileObject>();

        using (var response = (FtpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (responseStream == null)
                    return null;
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        string r = reader.ReadLine();
                        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r))
                            continue;
                        var reg = regex.Match(r);
                        var c = new FileObject
                        {
                            FileName = reg.Groups[6].Value,
                            IsDirectory = reg.Groups[1].Value.ToLower() == "d"
                        };
                        result.Add(c);
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
                response.Close();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

And this is my simple container FileObject class:

```
internal class FileObject
{
    public bool IsDirectory { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your calls to .Close() are redundant with the `using` block.  IDisposable.Dispose() will take care of that for each of these methods (unless there's a buggy implementation I'm not aware of).

Comment: Try enabling tracing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc(v=vs.110).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyb3xww8(v=vs.110).aspx Also try

Comment: @EricJ. - I went ahead and removed the Close() method calls. It didn't fix my problem, but you are right in that they aren't needed.

Comment: It would appear my issue was because I was using passive mode instead of active. Adding `request.UsePassive = false;` to my code fixed my issue.

Comment: Suggest you add that fact as an answer.  I can imagine others will stumble across the same problem.

Comment: @EricJ. - The calls to `Close` are certainly not needed, but I think it is good practice to include them as it makes the code clearer to read.

Comment: @Enigmativity: I disagree.  `using` and `IDisposable` is a core paradigm of .NET development.  Every .NET developer should know what is happening.  Adding redundant calls makes the code unnecessarily longer.

Comment: @EricJ. - By that logic you should limit variable, class, and method names to a single character to avoid unnecessarily long code. You're right that every developer should know what's happening, but it is a design decision that `.Dispose()` calls `.Close()`. It didn't explicitly have to so it has to be learnt and not every developer knows it. I think it is still better to be redundant when it aids code maintenance.

Comment: @Enigmativity: That is very different logic, not the same logic.  My logic is avoiding redundancy by leveraging established patterns.  Your logic is to write minimal code at the expense of clarity.

Comment: Nice code. +1. Though your problem is actually with listing a directory, so the question title is bit confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My issue appeared to be fixed by using Active mode instead of Passive. I added this to my code:

```
request.UsePassive = false;
```

This appears to fix my issue. I tested it on a large batch of files with lots of subdirectories and sub-subdirectories and it seems to work flawless now.